# "Fling in the Hay"

Tags: meaning, etymology

I have trouble finding anything about this. Google offers several quotes at the top of the results:

> - Rowena Cory Daniells, "[The King's Bastard](https://books.google.de/books?id=hFDlDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT100&lpg=PT100&dq=%22fling+in+the+hay%22&source=bl&ots=CAqr0fOJhJ&sig=ACfU3U0uU2W2L6IJGzEzO0tXvJRKGqqVJA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAobnw8ubgAhUnMuwKHS0mABAQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ)", 2016
>
> 'You fancy her!'
>   Lence nodded, 'And what's more, I've tasted her sweet fruit.'
>   'No, you never!'
>   'Autumn cusp, in the hay after the Harvest Feast.'
>   [...]
>   'She deserves Better than a **fling in the hay**, Lence.'
>   'Well, that's all I can offer, remember?' Lence snapped. 'I'm to be married to the Merofynian kingsdaughter. So, go ahead, woo her, marry her if she'll have you. But one day she will be my mistress.'
>
> - Elizabeth August, "[Cinderella Story 3](https://books.google.de/books?id=oflkAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT25&lpg=PT25&dq="fling+in+the+hay"&source=bl&ots=VLYicm293W&sig=ACfU3U3WWigIGF1TpA-K239ue-aeWoib1g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAobnw8ubgAhUnMuwKHS0mABAQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ), 2014
>
> "Besides, I like my independence. All I want is a little **fling in the hay** once in a while to satisfy my more primitive cravings, then I'm happy to be on my own again."

ngram finds nothing though, not even these google-books books.

It's pretty obvious that the saying relates to the "affair" definition of [fling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fling). So the preliminary question must be, which was first, **is fling in this sense just an ellipsis?**

The more current idiom seems to be [a roll in the hay](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331396/what-popularized-a-roll-in-the-hay-in-the-1940s), agreeing roughly with the trivial meaning of *fling* "to throw". There, it's noted that *hay* can be a synonym for bed, and that *roll in the hay* can mean inconspicious children's play, frolicking. One has to say *had meant*, actually, because the the daily live has changed. If there was a euphemism it's overt now, occluding the once obvious meaning.

Yet, I think I can read an inuendo in 1838

> Ingraham, J. H. (Joseph Holt) "Burton; or The Sieges Volume 2]()", 1838
>
> If it had been the spy-monk in thy case, he would not have let a maiden tuck him up **in the hay**, and leave him there to go to her lone pillow.

I'm trying to read *hay* as *hay field*, at least in some older instances of "in the hay", because I first associated German  [Springinsfeld](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49811/woher-kommt-springinsfeld/49913#49913) (lit. *jump into the field*; It's an appellation, not one of the usual long German compound words, it appears like a speaking name, like *Hans Guckindieluft* "Johnny Look-at-Air"), although I'm not sure what a "hay field" should be, if long grass becomes hay only after the harvest. Anyhow, there the answer currently says "Springinsfeld" was military jargon, relating to the battlefield, which in my humble opinion needn't be original.

As far as I know, "fling in the hay" does not describe a person, like "Springinsfeld" but it comes close e.g. in "All I want is a little fling in the hay".

Any far flung idea to connect these is welcome, if it can be possibly backed-up with sources.

The basic question is for the origin of fling in the given sense.

Comment: A "roll in the hay" is *always* sexual and consensual, *never* "inconspicuous children's play, frolicking."

Comment: @Robusto, you didn't read the links, I just repeated the obvious. In the city there is no hay, so the majority of readers cannot inconspicuously roll literally in the hay, that much is true.

Comment: If there an actual question here?

Comment: @PeterShor it's filed under *etymology*, isn't it?

Comment: It’s worth noting that of the four quotes in Sven Yargs’ answer to that question which deal with _roll in the hay_ as an innocent pastime, three are verbal. Usage has presumably changed over time, but I would agree with @Robusto that nowadays, nominal _a roll in the hay_ is always sexual. Even now, though, I find those cases of verbal _to roll in the hay_ in the innocent sense quite reasonable – the sexual meaning is much less overt when _roll_ is a verb rather than a noun.

Comment: I read your words, but they don't seem to add up to anything but some vague unease with idioms about *hay*. Can you summarize your problem and state an actual question here?

Comment: @vectory It’s tagged etymology, but it is lacking in specificity – are you looking for the earliest appearance of the phrase, where it came from/who coined it, which sense of _fling_ is the one that underlies it..? Etymology can be interpreted by several different aspects.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet if anything, it's *latest appearance*. You can't prove earliest appearance. You know what I mean. I'm not giving much on written evidence for euphemisms and taboo words. I'm hoping mostly for comparative evidence, internal, too. Alas, if it were indeed a recent coinage, I don't care much for it. *Springinsfeld* is 16th century at the latest, for good measure.

Comment: *To roll in the hay* is figurative even for childs play. It's almost like *run around* or *play marbles in the street*. It's certainly a metonym, otherwise the euphemism couldn't have developed.

Comment: @Robusto I'm looking to connect the phrase to the German one, however that's immaterial to this site.

Comment: It's never immaterial to state your actual issue rather than leave us to divine it. *Das sollte selbstverständlich sein.*

Comment: I'm thankful for the reminders and inquiries. I'd like to treat this like a search engine "OK google: Fling in the hay, etymology". It never works, so I add a bit of fluff. Often enough solving the *preliminary question*, that I was very explicit about, either solves the question, or helps to send it in the right direction. The fluff is still there, to add perspective, and as a personal note of sorts.

Comment: I've never heard 'fling in the hay' before. It sounds like someone mixed up 'fling' and 'roll in the hay'. The error may have a history (an oldest known appearance) but it'll still be a mistake (as a pleonasm).

Comment: @Mitch, it might just be a regional thing. Every word or phrase is a pleonasm at some point.

Comment: An Elephind search for "fling in the hay" yields 0 matches, versus 56 for "roll in the hay." Elephind is heavily weighted toward pre-1930 sources, so "fling in the hay" may have emerged as idiom in English in the past 90 years without leaving a trace in the U.S. and Australian newspapers that Elephind relies on; but a long and broad idiomatic existence is unlikely. The oldest Google Books match is from an Arkansas Philological Association (1987): "Girls, take my advice, And put away those knives; The boys will pay For a fling in the hay; But they don't want to pay For the rest of their lives;"

Comment: "Every word or phrase is a pleonasm at some point". I'm having trouble figuring out what you want to mean by 'pleonasm'. Most people think of it as 'redundant'. Most words or phrases do not become redundant.

Comment: Oh, I know, usually, but I should not post after midnight. I thought of neologism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instances of 'fling in the hay' I've been able to uncover in early (before 1995) popular news venues suggest that the phrase may have emerged as a synonym of 'roll in the hay' sometime before the 1980s.

The first appearance I found, in a hostile and contemptuous [1981](https://www.newspapers.com/image/471898204/?terms=%22fling%2Bin%2Bthe%2Bhay%22) review (paywalled) of a stage play, *A Very Modest Orgy*, greatly embellished the phrase, and seemed to be chiefly an attempt to dress up 'roll in the hay' with more contemporary language:

> Phoebe...may well want to test the unlikely sensual possibilities of a whipped-cream *fling in the hay* loft with another couple willing to swap sexual stamps.
>
> *Edmonton Journal* (Edmonton, Alberta, Canada) 13 Oct 1981, p. 31.

In the review, 'fling' means "a short period of unrestrained pursuit of one's wishes or desires" ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fling)).

The second appearance I found was a [1983](https://www.newspapers.com/image/213904314/?terms=%22fling%2Bin%2Bthe%2Bhay%22) teaser (paywalled) for an advice column:

> So, if his wife wants to have a little *fling in the hay*, what the hey?
>
> *News-Press* (Fort Myers, Florida) 05 Nov 1983, p. 41.

This 'fling' means what it did in the earlier use. All told, I don't see a material difference between the meaning of this "fling in the hay" and the meaning of the more common phrase 'roll in the hay'.

The third appearance I found was, like the first, embedded in a hostile review; the subject of the [1984](https://www.newspapers.com/image/460955871/) review (paywalled) was a mini-series TV adaptation of Hemingway's *The Sun Also Rises*.

> It concerns Jake Barnes, ...who has been emasculated by a German grenade — a matter of great concern to Lady Brett Ashley, who loves him dearly but can't do without her *flings in the hay*.

It could be argued with some justice that "rolls" would not work as well as "flings" in that sentence. However, the meaning is the same: 'fling' is used in the sense cited above, and 'the hay' is used in a sense recorded by [*OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84807?rskey=E5yGPQ&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid1821423) (paywalled):

> ***the hay***: colloq. phr. for 'bed'; esp. in phrases ***to roll in the hay***.

The fourth appearance of 'fling in the hay' I found in a [1987](https://www.newspapers.com/image/283834350/?terms=%22fling%2Bin%2Bthe%2Bhay%22) promotional blurb (paywalled) for the 1964 James Bond movie *Goldfinger*:

> The movie is remembered...for Bond's...fast *fling in the hay* with Pussy Galore....

All told, then, the sense of 'fling in the hay' I'm understanding from the uses so far is "a short period of unrestrained pursuit of one's wishes or desires" "in bed". The phrase with 'fling', like the phrase with 'roll', refers to "a brief sexual liaison". If there is any difference between the phrase with 'fling' and the phrase with 'roll', it is that 'fling' more readily admits interpretation as being a longer period than 'roll'.

The 1980s seem to have been the heyday for the 'in the hay' phrase with 'fling'. After 1987, the next appearance I found was in 1995, eight years later. After that appearance, 'fling in the hay' in the print press (at least so far as the [Newspapers.com](https://www.newspapers.com/) corpus is concerned) disappears for nine years, reappearing in 2004. Both the 1995 and the 2004 appearances were uses in the same sense as 'roll in the hay'.

Comment: @vectory, no more than I'd expect 'flinging', that is, not at all in that context. It ('rolls') does occur (2015, 2013, 1999), as does 'rolling' (2016, 2013 with 'around', 2007, 1997). I also find 'toss' (British, 2017), 'throw' (2012), 'romp' (2009), 'tussle' (2008), 'play' (2001, 1996), etc.

Answer (score 4):

"Fling in the hay" is a slightly mixed expression combining a "fling", meaning a brief sexual dalliance with no commitment, and "roll in the hay" meaning a casual sexual encounter (which may or may not be literally in the hay, depending on environment, but is probably somewhere other than a comfortable bed).

The modified expression probably extends "roll in the hay" to a few encounters, but not to the level of any kind of real relationship.

Comment: Oh, OK, I didn't see it like that. Given that I expected *fling* to be a shortening of the phrase, do you have anything to counter that claim? PS: The argument might still work analogously for the original sense *to fling, hurl*, if I understand correctly that a *fling* is a "violent motion", as wiktionary puts it; Compared to a smooth rockin' and rollin'.

Comment: Given Icelandic *flengur* "a fast sprint", comparing German *flink* "quick", and *flunkern* "sort of defensive lie", I could see *fling* meaning "to cheat", however the question remains the same, only in different proportions.

Comment: @vectory - If you want to ask for help figuring out the derivation of *fling* as "a brief sexual dalliance with no commitment," please post a separate question.

Comment: I think you could strengthen this answer by explaining explicitly that the image isn't of hay in a field, but in a barn or hay loft. // I would interpret "roll in the hay" as being a *spontaneous* sexual encounter, more than *casual*, and in fact, I think a roll in the hay could occur in an established relationship.  I think the key is the spontaneity.  That's how I see the phrase used, consistently.