# Is there another informal phrase for a roll in the sack/hay?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Merriam-Webster defines the phrase [roll in the hay](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20roll%20in%20the%20hay) as meaning:

> informal + old-fashioned
>   : an act of having sex with someone

I am aware that this may seem like a silly question at first, since there are hundreds, if not thousands of synonymous terms for it. I have looked through the lists at [Word Hippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/roll_in_the_hay.html), [Synonyms.com](https://www.synonyms.com/synonym/roll+in+the+hay) and [Power Thesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/roll_in_the_hay). Unfortunately, none of those fit into my context, which is:

> “Apparently, she had always preferred short, casual relationships, many of them amounting to nothing more than a few (rolls in the sack).”

The synonyms listed in my links are inapt because I consider them too crude or offensive in my usage case, and I must warn that they may cause discomfort in some sensitive individuals. I have not found a synonym listed in these references among the many that I am comfortable with or even remotely inclined to use if no one knows anything similar.

I am also not looking for anything too formal, though. [Tryst](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tryst) for instance (defined by Merriam-Webster as "an agreement (as between lovers) to meet" is alright, but a bit too formal for my context, and does not seem to directly imply the act of sexual intercourse itself.

I just want something relatively tasteful. Unfortunately, I am having a hard time coming up with a good phrase to replace *roll in the sack*, because there are not many that carry the same casual tone other than simply saying *sex*, which does not fit my usage case.

I am working on a novel, and in it, there is a character who used to be what many would probably refer to as *easy*. I have already used the phrase *a roll in the sack* more than once and just cannot bring myself to use it again, unless I have no other choice. If it were easy, I would simply reword my sentence, but its structure is perfect for the tone of the paragraph as it is in my opinion.

I am not looking for a term that nobody in their right mind would use in everyday conversation without expecting it to be understood. I would rather not confuse my readers and need them to look up the term to understand what it means. However, less common, but easily understood phrases or terms are acceptable.

Finally, I would prefer a phrase or word that I can directly replace *rolls in the sack* with without having to reword my sentence. However, if anyone has any suggestions for how my sentence might be reworded using a well known synonym without making it clunkier, then I am open to hearing them.

Comment: What I find depressing is that Mercian-Webster regards “having sex” as the standard formal expression for the plain English “fucking”. As a biological scientist I regard sex as the differentiating characteristic of animals capable of procreation. Admittedly the previous dictionary standard, “sexual intercourse” could be regarded as something of a euphemism in the tradition of the biblical “carnal knowledge” (a little knowledge can be a dangerous thing) but if we can’t have English, the Latin, “copulation” would surely serve.

Comment: @David What I find depressing is the downvotes I’ve gotten. I’m not sure if one of those was you or not, but, if so, could you explain why? I have an example sentence and the research I’ve done listed. Is it simply because of the sort of phrase I’m searching for?

Comment: No, I didn’t downvote your question. If I had, any comment I made would have explained why, rather than using your question to grind my own axe (there’s a possible sexual euphemism — at least in the grinding). I can only guess why others have down-voted your question — perhaps they don’t regard it as consistent with the remit of the site. It would be appear to be a request in helping your writing rather than a linguistic point. In addition it would seem to depend very much on period and culture.

Comment: It is not my vote, but I see a close vote for this question, which is for the too broad closure reason. I don't think it meets the current definition of the closure reason which requires you to limit the question to one specific solvable problem, but the former definition included something about too many possible answers. If that's the problem people have, then I'm not sure if the question can be fixed. You might try explaining what semantic elements of the synonyms are considered undesirable, to restrict the number of possible answers and help us differentiate better answers from worse ones.

Comment: @Tonepoet Thanks, I’ll be sure to include why those synonyms don’t work. Hopefully, it’ll better explain what I’m looking for. Also, just in case my edit ends up not helping, would it be better to delete the question before it’s closed? I don’t know which is worse as far as points are concerned.

Comment: It's a little complicated to explain, but the summarized version is that closure exists to give questioners a chance to remedy their questions if possible, and rarely amounts to more than a slap on the wrist.  Moreover, not everybody agrees on which questions should be closed, which is why it's left up to a privileged consensus or moderator discretion. I don't think it even makes a difference to the system why you deleted a question, and deleting an answered question depublishes the answers, so I'd recommend waiting, and maybe even discussing the matter on our local meta website.

Comment: @Tonepoet Thanks for the edit, looks much better now.

Comment: I'm more than a little depressed that they've branded a perfectly serviceable phrase *old-fashioned*.

Comment: You could say "a few quick tumbles" or (if that doesn't seem clear enough) "a few quick tumbles in [or _on_ or _under_ or _beneath_] the sheets." It's basically a refitting of "a roll in the hay" to a less bucolic setting.

Comment: @Sven Yargs Better than anything I’ve come up with and it fits. Honestly, this is trickier than most people would probably expect when reading the title. I’m leaning towards just taking out ‘a few’ and putting in ‘a one night stand’, even though I wanted to imply very brief, but established affairs (sort of), not just random encounters.

Comment: @P.M.B.: "One-night stands" narrows the behavior to one-off experiences only; "a series of brief tumbles" suggests that some of the character's fellow tumblers may have had a repeat performance or two, but that nothing seriously long-term ever developed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use euphemistic slang that is not overly crass, then I consider bed play is possibly worthy of consideration. The word *play* emphasizes that this is recreational activity, and bed is being used metonymically because most erotic acts take place in the bedroom. It is similar logic to the euphemistic use of *sleep with*, albeit with less ambiguity in my opinion, since there is not a commonplace alternative interpretation of the term, at least to my present knowledge.

Normally I would include a dictionary definition of the term, but surprisingly no formal dictionary seems to define it, so instead I will have to rely solely on copious examples of context to demonstrate the meaning:

> Tormand knew he would not have come to Clara's bedroom for a night of sweaty bed play. Clara had once been his lover, but their affair had ended and he never returned to a woman once he parted from her. He especially did not return to a woman who was now married and to a man as powerful and jealous as Sir Ranald Sinclair.

—[Silver Flame by Hannah Howell](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gg4Fx-varhkC&pg=PT456&dq="bed+play"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_3bjzgIjlAhUCvJ4KHbgzDtI4HhDoATAGegQIBBAC#v=onepage&q="bed%20play"&f=false)

> Karim smiled grimly. "Unlike you, my friend, I would feel most uncomfortable living with a woman who wanted to use a knife on me, regardless how exciting the bed-play was."

—[Sunburst's Citadel by Therese Nichols](https://books.google.com/books?id=7DmaAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA226&dq="bed+play"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_3bjzgIjlAhUCvJ4KHbgzDtI4HhDoATAIegQICRAC#v=onepage&q="bed%20play"&f=false)

> Conn raised his eyebrows. "If you are thinking to advising me on my sex life, I'll need another drink."
>
> "I am not talking about bed play. Or not only about that," Griff said. "The girl has been on Sanctuary less than a day. She needs time to adjust."

—[Sea Lord by Virginia Kantra.](https://books.google.com/books?id=7-GPVnxjCCcC&pg=PA124&dq="bed+play"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj02o3pgIjlAhUYuZ4KHZXIDyI4FBDoATAIegQIAhAC#v=onepage&q="bed%20play"&f=false)

> Dane nodded absently. Earthier, in regards to George, meant endowed with a great deal of bosom and a hearty appreciation for bed-play[.]

—[Surrender to a Wicked Spy
By Celeste Bradley](https://books.google.com/books?id=_tmiH3hyknEC&pg=PA61&dq=Earthier,+in+regards+to+George,+meant+endowed+with+a+great+deal+of+bosom+and+a+hearty+appreciation+for+bed-play&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnm4m_hojlAhUBvJ4KHa6LDmkQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=Earthier%2C%20in%20regards%20to%20George%2C%20meant%20endowed%20with%20a%20great%20deal%20of%20bosom%20and%20a%20hearty%20appreciation%20for%20bed-play&f=false)

> They do have strange, violent notions of bed play, Penrith,” Edenham said conversationally, staring down at Jane with a strange look in his green eyes, “do be warned. It's not unpleasant, but it is a bit unruly, even slightly barbaric.["]

—[Daring a Duke by Claudia Dain](https://postimg.cc/9DQFhPz4)

> Whether siblings sleep in the same bed or not depends ultimately on family finances. Problems of heterosexual or homosexual bed play seems not likely to arise before the age of five or six, and after that they may or may not.

—[The encyclopedia of Mental Health by Albert Duetsch](https://books.google.com/books?id=SQnoAAAAMAAJ&q="bed+play"&dq="bed+play"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0urDjhIjlAhXHpZ4KHcTmB5E4RhDoATAEegQIARAC)

---

The last of those contexts is not quite like your own, but it is important in that it is the earliest example I can find on Google Books (dated 1970), and to show that it is not so crass as to be beyond conceivable use in formal register, even if it is typically not found in such contexts.

That actually constitutes most of the examples I found in the Google Books library, but it is also worth noting that playwright and actress [Emma Carter](https://www.emmakcarter.com/plays) also wrote a play called Bed Play: The Elements of Intimacy in 2017, which aside from being a suggestive title also suggests that she trusts the meaning of the word to be well enough known to merit inclusion in her title.

There are some caveats. One is that it can be interpreted as a broader range of carnal acts, although I doubt that is much of a problem given the recreational nature of the described activity. The other is that it is noncount, so you would have to reform the sentence to end in "a little bed play" rather than "a few bed plays", and a distinction between using a count and non-count sentence is that the noncount sentence may be interpreted as a singular event rather than a small number of repeat encounters. However, at the same time it does not disinclude the possibility of multiple encounters and the gist of the sentence remains roughly the same.

Comment: This is a good one, might end up using it if nothing else comes up. Thanks for the example sentences.

Answer (score 0):

“Apparently, she had always preferred short, casual relationships, many of them amounting to nothing more than a few..."

- Turns in the cabbage
- Paphian jigs ("Dance the Paphian jig)

Answer (score 0):

> Fling

compare the answers at my related Question ["Fling in the Hay"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488134/fling-in-the-hay)

In the question, I underhandedly supposed that "fling" may describe a person. In that sense, use of the plural as in your example, "a few ~", strikes me as unlikely. Anyhow, fling implies a small amount, so the constraint "a few" is redundant, unless it ironically implied "many", "strictly more than one", "quite a few". However, as the ansseres showed, this is not commonly understood (not at all the case, they suggest), so it shouldn't be much of a problem.